# First login via https failed after logout?

Tags: java, apache, spring-security, tomcat7

I have application with following setup:

```
Apache --> Tomcat --> Spring based application
```

Login page is forced to be https by apache (redirect) and all other pages are http (redirect by apache).

When users logs in the login is fine and I can move to various pages. After log-out, I can see login page again, but when I try to login, I got redirected to

```
https://myapp.domain.com/%3bJSESSIONID=DF65717AD48DA91104331320FC5F0B10
```

and still see my login page. Only when I enter credentials again I'm able to log in. So after every logout I must enter credentials twice in order to login. What can be wrong here?

Here the security part of *config*

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="true">

    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/validate*" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>

    <security:logout logout-url="/temp/logout" logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="secretKey"/>

</security:http>
```

Comment: Please post your spring security config, are you invalidating the cookie?

Comment: What URL is your login page at? Is it at "/" ? If so then you may just be getting redirected since there is no other obvious place to go after login. Given that you are using Apache, HTTPS etc, all sorts of things can go wrong, but it's very difficult to say without more information. You really need to analyse the request and response data, check whether sessions are maintained, look at the debug log and explain your Apache and Tomcat setup in detail. Also, you have no security applied so in theory you can access the site without logging in at all.